# Combining 2 JSON Arrays into member roles (DISCORD.JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to merge 2 JSON arrays from my config file to push them to member roles

JSON Config

```
{
    "adminRoles": [
        "ADMIN",
        "LA REINA DE BELLEZA"
    ],
    "moderatorRoles": [
        "MODERATOR",
        "BOT"
    ]
}
```

And then push the combined 2 arrays into this

```
// This command must be limited to mods and admins.
if (!message.member.roles.some(r => [COMBINED_ROLES_HERE].includes(r.name))) {
return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

I've tried

```
console.log(client.config.adminRoles.concat(client.config.moderatorRoles));
```

And that returns

```
[ "ROLE 1", "ROLE 2" etc... ]
```

But that doesn't work. I've also tried to .join() and can return

```
"ROLE 1", "ROLE 2" etc...
```

But that also doesn't work.

Comment: How are you getting `[ "ROLE 1", "ROLE 2" etc... ]` when your values are `[
        "ADMIN",
        "LA REINA DE BELLEZA"
    ]` and `[
        "MODERATOR",
        "BOT"
    ]` ?

Comment: I just wrote those to illustrate the style of returns. I am actually returning ADMIN, LA REINA DE BELLEZA etc...

Comment: OK. What do you want to achieve? Please update the question with `message.member.roles`.

Comment: So when I do `if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["ADMIN",  "MODERATOR"].includes(r.name))) {` It works, so in my head when I concat and then join to return "ADMIN", "MODERATOR" etc... it should work, but the bot is replying with the message that I do not have the correct permissions, which is wrong because I have the admin discord role. So I am wondering if it's a limit of the discord.js or whether I am doing something wrong.

Comment: log the value of `COMBINED_ROLES_HERE ` and check if it is already an array.

Comment: Apparently it is returning a boolean - https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=some - so I guess I need to convert my array to boolean or string...

Comment: Isn't `COMBINED_ROLES_HERE ` is a merge array of `adminRoles` and `moderatorRoles`?

Comment: Yes when I use `client.config.adminRoles.concat(client.config.moderatorRoles)` it returns `[ "ADMIN", "MODERATOR" ]` so that is an array, but `.some` returns a boolean. Although even when I did `.join()` to make it a string it still didn't work - I used `'"' + client.config.adminRoles.concat(client.config.moderatorRoles).join('", "') + '"'`

Comment: `array#some` returns boolean result. Please share `message.member.roles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const roles = {
  "adminRoles": [
    "ADMIN",
    "LA REINA DE BELLEZA"
  ],
  "moderatorRoles": [
    "MODERATOR",
    "BOT"
  ]
}

const message = {
  member: {
    roles: [
      { name: 'testing 123' }
    ]
  }
};

// then push the combined 2 arrays into this
const combinedRoleNames = Object.keys(roles);
const combineRoles = combinedRoleNames
  .map(x => roles[x])
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), []);

console.log(combinedRoleNames);
console.log(combineRoles);

// if you want to assign to member.roles, uncomment following line
// message.member.roles = combineRoles.map(name => ({ name }));

if (!message.member.roles.some(r => combineRoles.includes(r.name))) {
  console.log('sorry');
  // return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use // this!");
} else {
  console.log('found');
}
```

Comment: So your saying that the roles can't live inside the config.json file?

Comment: This works by the way - I just question if the roles could still live inside the config.json file which can be accessed using client.config.adminRoles etc...

Comment: u can replace with your json value, the ocde above is for demo purpose.

Comment: replace the line `const combinedRoleNames = Object.keys(roles);` to `const combinedRoleNames = Object.keys(client.config);`, then you can remove the `roles` variable.